# Como acessar um ponteiro dentro de uma estrutura de ponteiro

Tags: c, ponteiro

Eu sei que para acessar uma variável normal dentro de uma estrutura de ponteiro eu posso utilizar essa sintaxe:

```
struct teste { 

    int valor;
    int *aponta;

};

struct teste testando, *testado;
testado = &testando;
testado -> valor = 10;
```

Porém, como acesso o ponteiro `aponta` que está contido na estrutura, utilizando o ponteiro `testado`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para fazer esse ponteiro apontar para algum lugar:

```
int teste2 = 123;
testado->aponta = &teste2;
```

Para alterar o valor do que é apontado:

```
*(testado->aponta) = 456;
```

E para ler o valor da variável:

```
*(testado->aponta)
```

Veja aqui um teste com o código completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct teste { 
    int valor;
    int *aponta;
};

int main() {

    struct teste testando, *testado;

    testado = &testando;
    testado->valor = 10;
    int teste2 = 123;
    testado->aponta = &teste2;
    *(testado->aponta) = 456;
    printf("%d %d", teste2, *(testado->aponta));
}
```

A saída é `456 456`. [**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/OoArJK)

Comment: Isto seria um operador `*(ptrStruct->member)`? Se sim, qual seria o nome dele? Não entendi o motivo de ter que envolver em parentese `()`  seguido de um asterisco `*` a estrutura.

Comment: @gato O parêntese serve para agrupar subexpressões. É o mesmo parêntese usado em `3 * (2 + 4)`. O operador unário `*` é o operador de dereferência e é usado para acessar o conteúdo de um ponteiro.

Comment: Valeu mesmo, eu não encontrei a resposta em outros locais, era quase meio obvio. É só colocar parenteses para respeitar a ordem de procedência e inserir o asterisco para pegar o valor de referencia;